# Grant non Sysadmin the ability to change max memory setting SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, stored-procedures, permissions

I've received a request to create a stored procedure that would allow a user (with access to the DB server) to change SQL Server's `max server memory (MB)`. This wasn't the hard part.

The other requirement is that this user should be able to change **this only parameter `max server memory (MB)` and nothing else**. What I'd like to know is, if this is possible.

I do realize that, to be able execute`sp_configure` and run`RECONFIGURE`, the minimum privilege required is `ALTER SETTINGS`. And providing `ALTER SETTINGS` would defeat the purpose of the stored procedure (which would be designed to run just `exec sys.sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)', @TheReqMemVal`) along with a minimum and maximum allowed value for `max server memory (MB)`.

After reading some of the comments, I'd like to add that if responses were to incorporate possible security pitfalls, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use [EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql) instead of giving permissions.

Comment: @ McNets he cannot use execute as in this case: if he uses execute as CLAUSE of the sp, he can executes only as a USER, not login, and the permission he needs is a SERVER LEVEL permission; the use of EXECUTE AS *statement* can use the login, but it requires impersonate permission ot that login

Comment: @sepupic only partially true. There are ways (read: don't do this) to elevate that user. See: https://sqlstudies.com/2014/02/26/impersonating-a-server-level-permissions/

Comment: @George.Palacios do you mean setting TRUSTWORTHY on for the database? For providing all the db_owners the opportunity to raise themselves to sysadmin? I don't consider it a solution at all

Comment: It is completely a solution to the issue at hand, but it does open up security holes. That's why I included the (read: don't do this)

Comment: @George.Palacios the article citated in my answer describes TRUSTWORTHY too, so who is interested in will find it too. I did not want to put it as the *anwer* because I cannot copy the entire article here to explain the consequences, and the "bads" that solution provides weight more than "goods", and if someone just take it as the solution without reading to what it can lead, I do not want to be someone who offered this "solution". But you can freely do this

Comment: When this setting (and many other settings)  is changed (or more specifically, when `RECONFIGURE` activates the change), SQL Server will clear it's cache. You should ensure that whoever gets permission to run this, they have proper training as to *when* it should happen.

Comment: While it's off topic for the question you asked, I'm curious why you want to do this. Whatever problem you're trying to solve might have a different solution than altering max memory frequently by non-DBAs

Comment: Using impersonate/trustworthy can be done semi-safely by creating a separate DB to hold the SP. Then grant ONLY connect to the DB & execute to the SP  for the users that you want to have those permissions.  No other permissions in/on that DB. That way only sysadmins can connect & create SPs that could cause problems. (And hopefully you trust them to know what they are doing)

Answer (score 6):

You should use signed procedure in this case.

The greate article [Signing Procedures with Certificates by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#Certificates) explains it well, and here are the steps to perform:

- Create a certificate in the master database.
- Create a login for that certificate.
- Grant that login ALTER SETTINGS.
- Export the certificate to file.
- Switch to the application database.
- Import the certificate from the file.
- Delete the file from disk.
- Create a user for the certificate.
- Sign the stored procedure with the certificate, each time you have
  changed the procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the details, @sepupic. I'll have to try this on my test server and if I'm able to get it to work, I will mark this as the answer. However, implementing this in our prod environment is going to be a whole different battle (given that I'll have to look into any security concerns (if you are aware of any such, do update this post...nevertheless, I to appreciate your response, thanks again).